# VBA Loop through images in a folder and find a similar match

Tags: vba

I have a folder with many images for products. There are multiple images for each product. I need to identify ones that start with my product number (e.g., 100100) and end with one of two endings "_FRONT" or "_ALTERNATE". There is other information between those two. For example, file names could be 100100_headset_FRONT or 100100_headset_SIDE. I want it to find the front or alternate image for each product.

I have been successful at pulling the images and I think I am close on the way to name call the file but not quite there. The code returns the error "The specified file wasn't found"

```
Sub PictureP()
Dim picname As String, picend As String
Dim PicPath As String
Dim lThisRow As Long
Dim Pic As Shape
Dim rngPic As Range


lThisRow = 3

Do While (Cells(lThisRow, 2) <> "")

    Set rngPic = Cells(lThisRow, 1) 'This is where picture will be inserted

    picname = Cells(lThisRow, 2) 'This is the picture name
    picend = "_FRONT"

    present = Dir("H:\Media\Images\1 Web Ready\Previews\" & picname & "*" & picend & ".jpg")
    PicPath = ("H:\Media\Images\1 Web Ready\Previews\" & picname & "*" & picend & ".jpg")


If present <> "" Then

      Set Pic = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(PicPath, msoFalse, msoCTrue, 1, 1, -1, -1)

    Else

    Cells(lThisRow, 1) = ""

    End If

lThisRow = lThisRow + 1
Loop

Range("B3").Select
On Error GoTo 0
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Exit Sub

End Sub
```

The code returns the error "The specified file wasn't found"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dir()` is evaluating the `*` wildcard correctly and returning the FIRST value that matches.

`PicPath =` is setting a string value.  Setting string values doesn't care about wildcards so its being added as a literal value.

If you debug and print out the two values during run-time you'd see the `*` in your PicPath.

Simplest solution is to just change the picPath to use the result of `Dir`, `present` and append it to the directory that `Dir()` searched.

See below.

```
Sub PictureP()
Dim picname As String, picend As String
Dim PicPath As String
Dim lThisRow As Long
Dim Pic As Shape
Dim rngPic As Range


lThisRow = 3

Do While (Cells(lThisRow, 2) <> "")

    Set rngPic = Cells(lThisRow, 1) 'This is where picture will be inserted

    picname = Cells(lThisRow, 2) 'This is the picture name
    picend = "_FRONT"

    present = Dir("H:\Media\Images\1 Web Ready\Previews\" & picname & "*" & picend & ".jpg")
    PicPath = ("H:\Media\Images\1 Web Ready\Previews\" & present)


If present <> "" Then

      Set Pic = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(PicPath, msoFalse, msoCTrue, 1, 1, -1, -1)

    Else

    Cells(lThisRow, 1) = ""

    End If

lThisRow = lThisRow + 1
Loop

Range("B3").Select
On Error GoTo 0
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Exit Sub

End Sub
```